# Why not allow the href attribute in tags other than the anchor? - EG: <h1 href=""></h1>

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I've just been going through a my current project and removing excess html and css where not needed, removing divs around abjects that didn't need a div for example and I was wondering, why do we need achors around everything:

```
<a href="Cake">
    <div>
        <p>This is not a lie.</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Why not allow simply allow:

```
<div href="Cake">
    <p>This is not a lie.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In a word? Semantics.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the `a` around the whole div. If you're making a link, you can just do this: `<p><a href="cake">This is not a lie.</a></p>`.

Comment: @ialarmedalien: Those do very different things…

Comment: @j08691 Is that necessary? I can clearly see where a DIV begins and ends.

Comment: @AirCombat: Do you actually understand what the `a` tag and it's `href` property do? They create a hyperlink and you'd throw it away.

Comment: Yes, it's necessary. Otherwise you could extend your argument to the extreme and say why not have just one element `<element>` and allow every attribute and property on it?

Comment: @j08691 That would make writing a validator so much easier! ;)

Comment: I don't agree. P, H1, ASIDE, FOOTER all describe the content symantically, <A> does not, it is like width:100px;, it describes a property surely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: As j08691 why should you use P, H1, ASIDE ? and not simply <ELEMENT text-group="P"> or <ELEMENT text-level="H1">. Because it wouldn't be readable. You see "A" you know it is a hyperlink, you see H1 you know is Header

Comment: No, it doesn't describe a property, because only `a` elements, i.e. hyperlinks, are interpreted by browsers as being links.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I'm not asking if it's incorrent, we know this. Im just interested in the logic behind why that decision was taken

Comment: @AirCombat You might email someone from the [w3c staff](http://www.w3.org/People/) and get your answer.

Comment: Tim Berners-Lee formulated the original HTML spec (see http://www.w3.org/History/19921103-hypertext/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/Tags.html), so ask him.

Comment: So I shouldn't ask questions on Stack Overflow when I can contact a 3rd party?

Comment: StackOverflow is specifically for programming problems; this isn't a programming problem--it's a conceptual one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm overly simplifying here, but it's about the concepts.

In HTML, every tag has a meaning and a function. Sometimes it's purely aesthetics (`<b>`, bold text), sometimes it's semantics (`<span>`, a new chunk of inline text), sometimes both (`<h1>`, a header starts here). The point is to *mark* portions of text with *semantics*.

The `<a>` tag is a hyperlink. Almost everything between `<a>` and `</a>` is supposed to behave like this: if clicked, jump to certain URL. Now that URL is a property of the `<a>` tag and you specify it via `href`.

This `href` does not make any sense outside of the `<a>` tag since back when HTML was born, CSS and JavaScript didn't exist so you couldn't do things like making a `<span>` clickable like we can today. But even today, it doesn't make sense to allow elements to adopt functionality of other elements as it taints their *semantics*.

In your second example you have completely removed the `<a>` tag, so it isn't a link any more. Even if the parser allows `href` on the `div`, it'd be wrong to suddenly make it behave like an `a` tag since it isn't.

Comment: A lot of our customers like to right click links and open in a new tab/window in a second monitor.  We also like entire rows to be clickable to open a record (especially if a custom column layout omits columns with any anchor tags).  A great solution would be to support the href attribute on other tags such as TR or DIV.  But in order to support right click open and clickable rows simultaneously, you have to jump through a lot of hoops.  Especially when you want to change those links on the fly.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your case?