# I keep getting 'None' when getting href links from HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, href

So I'm currently trying to build a function that retrieves the href links for each tag, but when I print my function, it returns none instead of the links.

I used:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('.titleline')
votes = soup.select('.score')


def create_custom_hn(links, votes):
    hn = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(links):
        title  = links[idx].getText()
        href = links[idx].get('href')
        hn.append(href)

    return hn

print(create_custom_hn(links, votes))
```

But my output was:

[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

I tried changing my function to

```
def create_custom_hn(links, votes):
    hn = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(links):
        title  = links[idx].getText()
        href = links[idx].find('a').get('href')
        hn.append(href)
    return hn

print(create_custom_hn(links, votes))
```

and this returned the links, however I know that in some cases the tag may not be an 'a' tag, and so I wanted my code to be applicable to any and all tags within the HTML code for the website.

Any suggestions??

Comment: You would need an `<a>` tag to use the `href` attribute, obviously. It is simply a matter of HTML and semantics. You cannot have the link attribute without the anchor element. So unless I fail to understand you here as to what exactly you mean by "href links for each tag", you are simply violating HTML semantics by using `get()` the way you have used it at first. Also, you may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488763/why-not-allow-the-href-attribute-in-tags-other-than-the-anchor-eg-h1-href#:~:text=Now%20that%20URL%20is%20a,clickable%20like%20we%20can%20today.).

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I was confused because what I did in the first example was something I followed step by step in a video from a course that I am taking, and he was able to get the links, but of course it did not work for me. And when I researched it elsewhere, just as you said I would need the <a> tag to use the href. But I still wanted to make sure just in case there was something else that could have been done differently with the code from my first example. Thank you!

Comment: Was the video scraping the same web site? You need to tailor your code to the specific HTML of each web site.

Comment: Yes, it was the same site, but the video was maybe from 2020 or 2019? So I'm certain there have been some changes to the HTML of the website.

Comment: Okay I just figured out what I was doing wrong in comparison. In the code from the video, the instructor was using `.storylink` which is now `.titleline`. Of course he made a note that it was changed to `.titleline`, but I realize that in order to apply the `<a>` tag , I could either do what I did in the second example, or include it in my link variable which would be `links = soup.select('.titleline > a')`. Once I changed this, and kept the function from my first example, I was able to get the href links.